# deleting a task from todoapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hello can you pls explain me how should I delete my task from a todo app?

My show_html_erb form looks like this:

this is my third day learning ruby i am quite confused i saw the documentation did the same but it just not listening to my commands:(

```
    <%= form_for([@todo_list, @todo_item]) do |f| %>

    <div class="input-group mb-4">
        <%= f.text_field :description , class:"form-control", placeholder:'Add todo items'%>
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <%= f.submit 'Add', class:"btn btn-primary input-group-btn"%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%end%>

    <ul class='list-group'>
        <% @todo_list.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
        <% if todo_item.completed?%>
        <li class='list-group-item bg-light'>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <span class="text-muted">

                    <em> <%= todo_item.description%></em>




                </span>
                **<%= link_to 'DELETE',todo_list_path(todo_item),method: :delete, class:'btn btn-dark'%>**  ------>> **THISSSS**



                <%= link_to '#', class:'btn btn-dark' ,data:{reflex: 'click->TodoItem#mark_incomplete',id:todo_item.id} do%>
                <i class='fas fa-undo-alt'></i>
                <%end%>
            </div>



        </li>
        <%else%>
        <li class='list-group-item'>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <span>

                    <%= todo_item.description%>


                </span>
                <%=   link_to 'Destroy', todo_list_path(todo_item),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ,class:'btn btn-dark'%> ------>> THIIIISSSSS

                <%= link_to '#', class:'btn btn-info',data:{reflex: 'click->TodoItem#mark_complete',id:todo_item.id} do %>
                <i class='fas fa-check'></i>
                <%end%>
            </div>



        </li>

        <%end%>


        <%end%>



    </ul>
</div>
```

what do i give wrong ,( i suppose the path , when i delete )

My todolist  controller looks like this:

```
class TodoListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /todo_lists
  # GET /todo_lists.json
  def index
    @todo_lists = TodoList.all
  end

  # GET /todo_lists/1
  # GET /todo_lists/1.json
  def show
    @todo_item = TodoItem.new
  end

  # GET /todo_lists/new
  def new
    @todo_list = TodoList.new
  end

  # GET /todo_lists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /todo_lists
  # POST /todo_lists.json
  def create
    @todo_list = TodoList.new(todo_list_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /todo_lists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /todo_lists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.update(todo_list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todo_lists/1
  # DELETE /todo_lists/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
    @todo_list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todo_lists_url, notice: 'Todo list was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_todo_list
      @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def todo_list_params
      params.require(:todo_list).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

Comment: The problem is not specific enough, e.g. is it that the action, `#destroy`, is not being called, you can check this by using a debugger like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and adding `binding.pry` in the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not passing the correct object/path to `delete`. Try the below code.

```
<%=   link_to 'Destroy', todo_item,
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ,class:'btn btn-dark'%>
```

And I believe the **html** which you shared above is `index.html.erb` not `show.html.erb`

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but it doesnt work like that if i run it like that the terminal says:

NoMethodError in TodoLists#show

undefined method `todo_item_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fe40c0bac00>:0x00007fe41c0914f8>

Comment: `todo_item_path` , I only used `todo_item`, have you appended path?

Answer (score 0):

So i found the answer , what i had to do is linking the delete method like that:

```
 <%=   link_to 'Destroy', todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list,todo_item),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ,class:'btn btn-dark'%>
```

that fixed my problem ( the reason why is because as you could see in my show.html.erb file that ive used a nested scaffold )